# Magento get media image size (file on server, no request)

Tags: php, magento-1, image

for our slider we want to detect the image size/width to set the attribute correctly

Now we use

```
$_img = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $s['image'];
$_imgsize = getimagesize($_img);
```

Only recently realizing that this code generates a request via http

**question:** how can we get the imagesize through the server directly? (what do we need to feed getimagesize as directory) - or is there a better way?

Comment: `getOriginalSizeArray()` in `catalog/Helper/Image.php` returns the image size.May be this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the GD image class. Read more about that on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php).

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . $s['image']);
$width = imagesx(image);
$height = imagesy(image);
```

Although in my opinion this is too heavy to do at run time and a waste of server resources. 
Could you expand on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Set the width and height attribute in HTML for the image (instead of leaving it blank)

Comment: it's a bit of a resource heavy operation just to set the  width and height. You might want to reconsider

Answer (score 1):

Use `getBaseDir()`  instead of `getBaseUrl()`.

This should work:

```
    $_imgsize = getimagesize(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $s['image']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also use `Varien_Image` class:

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') ... ;
$image = new Varien_Image($path);
$x = $image->getOriginalWidth();
$y = $image->getOriginalHeight();
```